# The element is defined but it continues returning undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this Javascript project. The span elements where created and defined in the javascript code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="C:\Users\Juan\Desktop\JavaScript Projects\animatedhead1\style.css">
    <title>Fancy</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 class="fancy">Juan de Tomaso</h1>



    <!--Here goes my Javascript-->


    <script>
        const text=document.querySelector('.fancy');
const strText=text.textContent;
const splitText=strText.split("");
text.textContent="";

for(let i=0;i<splitText.length;i++){
    text.innerHTML+="<span>"+splitText[i]+"</span>"; 
}

let char=0;
let timer=setInterval(onTick, 40);

function onTick(){
    let span=text.getElementsByTagName('span');
    span[char].classList.add('fade');
    char++;
    if(char===splitText.lenght){
        complete();
        return;
    }
}

function complete(){
    clearInterval(timer);
    timer=null; 
}
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I run it it returns that span is not defined so it cannot read the property classList. Any help for this? Because span is defined, so I dont know.

Comment: the error is valid, you don't have any `span` tag inside your <body></body> tag

Comment: Hi Sunny.The span elements where create in the javascript code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you have a **typo** on this line `(char === splitText.length)`. So let's do this way, it will add the class `fade` with every tick and clear the interval after completing all the characters. See fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/39dspma1/

```css
.fade {
  color: red;
}
```

```js
const text = document.querySelector('.fancy');
const strText = text.textContent;
const splitText = strText.split("");
text.textContent = "";

for (let i = 0; i < splitText.length; i++) {
  text.innerHTML += "<span>" + splitText[i] + "</span>";
}

let char = 0;
let timer = setInterval(onTick, 400);

function onTick() {
  let span = text.getElementsByTagName('span');
  span[char].classList.add('fade');
  char++;
  if (char === splitText.length) {
    complete();
    return;
  }
}

function complete() {
  clearInterval(timer);
  timer = null;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="C:\Users\Juan\Desktop\JavaScript Projects\animatedhead1\style.css">
  <title>Fancy</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1 class="fancy">Juan de Tomaso</h1>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi! thanks for the answer. I have to tell you that I create the span elements in here: for (let i = 0; i < splitText.length; i++) { text.innerHTML += "<span>" + splitText[i] + "</span>"; }  That's why I don;t know where the problem is.

Comment: @JuandeTomaso ohh I missed that somehow :) also you had some typo on the length property. See my added snippet. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

With following line:

```
let span=text.getElementsByTagName('span');
```

you are trying to get all HTML-Elements which have following tag name:

```
<span></span>
```

This is missing in your HTML code.

Adding it will help you out.

Comment: Hi Steff, I create the span elements in here:                                                                        for (let i = 0; i < splitText.length; i++) {
  text.innerHTML += "<span>" + splitText[i] + "</span>";
}

Answer (score 0):

You need the `children`. Do `text.children` instead of `getElementsByTagName`

```js
const text = document.querySelector('.fancy');
const strText = text.textContent;
const splitText = strText.split("");
text.textContent = "";

for (let i = 0; i < splitText.length; i++) {
  text.innerHTML += "<span>" + splitText[i] + "</span>";
}

let char = 0;
let timer = setInterval(onTick, 1000);

function onTick() {
  let span = text.children;
  span[char].classList.add('fade');
  char++;
  if (char === splitText.length) {
    complete();
    return;
  }
}

function complete() {
  clearInterval(timer);
  timer = null;
}
```

```css
.fade {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="fancy">Juan de Tomaso</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

i think its typo error

in onTick() change as follow in if condition

if(char===splitText.length){

}

Answer (score 0):

You have spelling mistake of **lenght** inside **onTick** function.Correct that and that should work fine.

Correction:

```
if(char===splitText.length)
```